# Background image-Full scale

Tags: jquery, css

You'll need to open the following page with edge or mozilla.
Here is the page: [codepen.io](http://codepen.io/sterg/full/NAVWay/) 
Here is what I have tried:

```
html{
  max-height:1900px;
  max-width:2600px;
}
```

So when the visitor zooms out I don't want the image to shrink and reveal the white space. I want the image to stay the same and zoom out. I hope that what I say makes some sense.

Note: I use jquery to get the background image.

```
document.body.style.backgroundImage = "url(http://eskipaper.com/images/sunny-day-4.jpg)";
```

Comment: It's under development..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why would you load an image to the body using jquery? That's an overkill. You can just load it via CSS:

```
html { 
  background: url('http://eskipaper.com/images/sunny-day-4.jpg') no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

This will make your image stay fixed size on zoom. There's no need for javascript.

Live example: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZONGZX

Comment: I need to change the background image depending on the data I get from the weather API.This is what I need to accomplish though.

Comment: Updated on codepen. It does the same thing using jquery now. Is this what you want?

Comment: Also,do you know what can I do to make this work on chrome?

Comment: It works fine in chrome for me. What exactly is the problem in chrome?

Comment: Well,I can't get the geolocation.

Comment: Sorry but what does geolocation have to do with background image cover? That's something completely different. I suggest you to google it or post a new question specially for geolocation.